# How can I update database on client side page in nextjs?

Tags: next.js, sequelize.js

I want to add a database entry based on user clicking a specific button. The only way I can see is by creating a Next API and calling a fetch to update the database.

The issue is that anyone can go to the API endpoint directly (without clicking the specific button) and add an entry to the database.

How do I stop this?

async function complete() {
const res = await fetch(`/api/add/user?id=${id}`);
const data = await res.json();
}

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to protect the route, for example by confirming that the user is permitted perform the requested action on the server.

For example, if you're using NextAuth, this is from https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/nextjs

```
import { authOptions } from 'pages/api/auth/[...nextauth]'
import { getServerSession } from "next-auth/next"


export async function handler(req, res) {
  const session = await getServerSession(req, res, authOptions)

  if (!session) {
    res.status(401).json({ message: "You must be logged in." });
    return;
  }

  return res.json({
    message: 'Success',
  })
}
```